# Ensembles Linking with OS X Swift App

Tags: swift, ensembles

I'm trying to incorporate `Ensembles 1.0` into my `Cocoa` app (`Swift`). Followed instructions to the letter, and it cleanly compiles. Can't get past some link errors though:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CDESetCurrentLoggingLevel", referenced from:
      InitClients.AppDelegate.applicationDidFinishLaunching (Foundation.Notification) -> () in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDEICloudFileSystem", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDEPersistentStoreEnsemble", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I've got `Ensembles.h` being imported in my bridging header, of course, otherwise there's a compiler error. And I've made sure that the `ensembles framework` references in the Build Phases is the OS X framework, not the iOS framework.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like it isn't finding any of the Ensembles classes. Did you actually link the framework to your app? And add a copy phase into the Frameworks?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem...silly mistake. I could have sworn I had dragged the Ensembles.framework into the project at one time, but I must have overlooked it. Dragging it in made it link just fine.